# Bootstrap single level menu using nested angular ng-repeat

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I am trying to make a bootstrap single level menu using angularJS.
It already works with js and html when the `<li>` is dynamically built.

Now I am trying to use AngularJS.

Suppose I have a JS object which has Cust and then orders inside.
How can I make a list menu

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="cust in customers">
    <p>{{cust.name}}</p>
    <li ng-repeat="order in cust.orders">
      <p>{{order.desc}}</p>
    </li>
  </li>
<ul>
```

This doesn't load properly (overlapping items) as the first `li` can't be closed.

Comment: You last `<ul>` is unclosed as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Christopher is right, you can't do without `<ul>`.

I think you can do this to have a one level menu :

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="cust in customers">
        <p>{{cust.name}}</p>
        <div ng-repeat="order in cust.orders">
            <p>{{order.desc}}</p>
        </div>
   </li> 
<ul>
```

And perhaps play with CSS to style in the way you want.

Or this, too :

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="cust in customers">
        <p>{{cust.name}}</p>
        <p ng-repeat="order in cust.orders">
            {{order.desc}}
        </p>
   </li> 
<ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's invalid markup, you're missing a `ul`

Try

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="cust in customers">
    <p>{{cust.name}}</p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="order in cust.orders">
          <p>{{order.desc}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

That should render it correctly, your bindings are correct.

Comment: This is what I don't want to do. My question is : how I can make it a menu of one level only. Is there a way to do this ? 
    <ul> 
    <li ng-repeat="cust in customers"> 
    <p>{{cust.name}}</p>
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="order in cust.orders">
    <p>{{order.desc}}</p>
    </li>
    <ul>

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you're trying to do. You can have both li's direct children of the ul repeat, but not am li inside. You can change the second ng-repeat to use a div or something instead.